# Two conditions for two different variables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, attr

I have this function:

```
settings_rc_left.on('click', function(){
    var settings_list_last_element_id_one = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'r_02',
        settings_list_last_element_id_two = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'l_02';
    if (settings_menu_element.first().attr('id') === settings_list_last_element_id_one) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (settings_menu_element.first().attr('id') === settings_list_last_element_id_two) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        renumPrev()
    }
});
```

and the html, this is simple list, for two condition i change id's to l_02, ... in other function, ...:

```
<ul id="settings_content_menu">
    <li id="r_02" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_03" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_04" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_05" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_06" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_07" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_08" class="">data</li>
    <li id="r_09" class="">data</li>
</ul>
```

What i'm trying to do is stop function for two different conditions depends on two different variables, and if it's not true fire up this function. Something is not right, can you help me?

Comment: Please show your HTML and what `settings_menu_element` is.  We can't debug your code without the ability to understand it or understand what you're trying to do.  Please also explain the goal of your event handler.

Comment: Are you aware you're setting `settings_list_last_element_id_one` and `settings_list_last_element_id_two` to boolean `true` or `false`? So it probably doesn't make sense to compare them to an `id` in the `if` and `else` conditions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

```
var settings_list_last_element_id_one = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'r_02'
```

the variable `settings_list_last_element_id_one` is either `true` or `false`. If you do not use `true` or `false` as IDs (and I hope you do not) the following can never be true:

```
settings_menu_element.first().attr('id') === settings_list_last_element_id_one
```

Comment: That's probably not the only thing wrong as `settings_menu_element.attr('id')` and `settings_menu_element.first().attr('id')` look like one is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem, here is the solution:

```
settings_rc_left.on('click', function(){
    var settings_list_last_element_id_one = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'r_02',
        settings_list_last_element_id_two = settings_menu_element.attr('id') == 'l_02';
    if (settings_list_last_element_id_one || settings_list_last_element_id_two) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        renumPrev()
    }
});
```